# When running java class in a java software tool unsure what property to set with "Classpath"

Tags: java, eclipse, classpath

I'm running some tests on a software tool on some java classes from the **command line** and its asking for classpath of a class in this format: "-classpath _____". I have attached and image here and would greatly appreciate if someone can take a look at it (the most recent tries are on the bottom, and I'm mousing over the java class I'm trying to run the software tool on in Eclipse to the top right).

Image: [The directory is shown on top left of screen on the title bar of eclipse.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mXgKn.jpg)

You can see at the bottom of the command line that my most recent attempt and the messages that it's replying that its an unknown class and for me to make sure its the correct classpath.

For the class I have to put after '- class' and I have put '-class CBranchExample' as my class is CBranchExample.java.

For the classpath I thought it meant directory its stored in: C:\Users\Kranti\Desktop\evosuite-master\master\src\test\java\com\examples\with\different\packagename\cbranch, and so I put in the command line: 'CProject C:\Users\Kranti\Desktop\evosuite-master\master\src\test\java\com\examples\with\different\packagename\cbranch'.

But there are still errors, but its not a fatal error that only appears if I put a random classpath or the wrong syntax for a class.

Edit: I mean in other words, what is it asking for when it's asking for CLASSPATH when I've already tried the directory of the place I saved my class?

Answer (score 2):

From documentation: http://www.evosuite.org/documentation/commandline/

Here is a working example:

`java -jar evosuite.jar -class [inner class] -projectCP [Full path + filename + .jar]`

The following will open `TestProject.jar` form the same folder and target the `MyTest.Test` class.

`java -jar evosuite.jar -class MyTest.Test -projectCP ./TestProject.jar`